# Google subscriptions validation returns error code 400 Invalid

Tags: android, google-api, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Our app have a subscription option with various tiers.

We are validating the subscription tokens via the Google Purchases.subscriptions.get method :

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/packageName/purchases/subscriptions/subscriptionId/tokens/token
```

When validating some subscription tokens, we keep getting the following error :

```
{"error"=>{"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"global", "reason"=>"invalid", "message"=>"Invalid Value"}], "code"=>400, "message"=>"Invalid Value"}, "status"=>400}
```

While many of the subscriptions are okay, we are still experiencing a high volume of such "Invalid Value" validation responses.

At first we suspected it might be due to usage of apps like [Lucky Patcher](https://www.wattpad.com/125568455-lucky-patcher-tutorial-hack-in-app-purchase) as mentioned here : [enter link description here](http://mgeeky.com/how-to-hack-in-app-purchases-without-root/) but it seems to cumbersome to be so common.

Please advice!